# How to put urdf in parameter server?

Tags: ros, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the urdf format robot in parameter server similarly like xacro format like below? :

```
<!-- Convert an xacro and put on parameter server -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find pr2_description)/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro" />

<!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model pr2" />
```

I have downloaded a robot model in urdf, but its very large so it's little hard to convert it into xacro format. So i want to directly use it, but what to for this robot_description parameter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267328/how-to-put-urdf-in-parameter-server?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is documented on the [roslaunch/XML/param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) page:

> `textfile="$(find pkg-name)/path/file.txt"`

> The contents of the file will be read and stored as a string. The file must be locally accessible, though it is strongly recommended that you use the package-relative `$(find)/file.txt` syntax to specify the location.

So for `robot_description`, that would be:

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find pkg-name)/path/file.urdf"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3